# Keep exported symbol in shared library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I must be missing something trivial. I want to declare a class for export — just one among several in a module. It is not used anywhere in the same library, so the linker strips it. Giving everything `hidden` visibility and the exported one `default` does not help to cajole the linker.

If I tell the linker `--whole-archive`, it complains about multiple definitions of completely unrelated functions. Besides, I don't want to export everything — just the one class.

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
class C { public: C() { } };
#pragma GCC visiblity pop

// with this line the class is exported
// without it — it does not
delete new C();
// the line does nothing useful,
// just references the constructor
```

Comment: Not a Linux expert. But from projects I was in I know you can do with shared libraries the same as you can do with windows DLLs. The syntax is a bit different but you end with the same export macros. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html) you can read about it.

Comment: Yes, in Windows with Visual C++ I could have trivially specified `__dllexport`.

Comment: In a nutshell: compile with `-fvisibility=hidden`and then build yourself the export macros as shown at the bottom of the page I linked in my first comment.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that it doesn't help.

Comment: All that works from gnu compiler 4.0 upwards I think. Maybe you did some trivial mistake - like forgotten -shared linker option or alike?

Comment: Did not forget the option. Visibility settings work as intended, but only as long as the class is actually used in the library.

Comment: So, you use g++ and do everything as described here http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility for SomeClass, don't you?

Comment: I use nvcc (CUDA compiler) which itself defers to g++.

Comment: Is it possible just to test the example from the link on your computer with g++ ?

Comment: @DonReba You probably should paste the exact command that gets run. When creating a shared library the usual way, g++ will not eliminate unused objects or symbols that's externally visible the same way it does when you're creating an executable.

Comment: Just tried it on my FreeBSD virtual machine. Command line arguments should be the same as for gcc toolchain. I did not use your --whole-archive switch and the class I exported was not used within the shared library. And it worked right away. -fpic for position independent code, of course and using clang -shared instead of using ld directly. g++/gcc also has -shared option. Should be the same.

Comment: To be sure, are you defining and exposing this class inside a header file visbile to both your library and your application? Inline classes are going to be.. well.. inline, and will thus not be visible to your executable (or other modules, for that matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, although CUDA's nvcc compiler can be instructed to use gcc for compilation, it still does the linking itself. And it does not do it the same way as gcc.